# How to solve $x[n]\ast x[n]=u[n]$?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, z-transform

I came across the following question:

> The causal discrete-time signal $x[n]$ satisfies:
> $$x[n]\ast x[n]=u[n]$$
> Where $\ast$ is the convolution operator and $u[n]$ is the discrete unit step function. Knowing that $x[0]>0$, compute $x[3]$.

My first attempt, from intuition was to apply the Z-transform to the equation, but I get the following strange thing:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{Z}\left\{x[n]\ast x[n]\right\}&=\mathcal{Z}\left\{u[n]\right\}\\
X[z]^2&=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}\\
X[z]&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^{-1}}}
\end{align}

Which is not something I have seen before on Z-transform tables. I could probably try to apply the inverse Z-transform from the definition, but I am not sure I would get somewhere.

Also, this question comes from a test where the idea is to be able to give straightforward answers, avoiding computations as much as possible, given the time constraints.

Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y[n] \triangleq x[n]*x[n],n\geq 0$, with $x[n]= 0,n< 0$ (causal sequence). By definition of the convolution operation, it holds

$$
\begin{align}
y[0] &= (x[0])^2 \\
y[1] &= 2x[0]x[1] \\
y[2] &= 2x[0]x[2]+(x[1])^2\\
y[3] &= 2(x[0]x[3]+x[1]x[2])
\end{align}
$$

By assumption, $y[n]=1, n\geq 0,$ and $x[0]\neq 0$, and you can solve these equations to find $x[3]$.